# Copy all files in a directory with a particular string in the filename to different directory in Bash

Tags: file, bash, copy, filenames, directory

For example, a directory could contain the files

```
12_foo9.dat
34foo32.txt
24foobar.png
997_bar.txt
```

and I would like to copy the files with 'foo' in the file names to a separate directory so that it would contain those first three files but not the fourth.

I've looked around but haven't figured out a way to do this. The directory has a very large number of files, but only 1% or so that I need to copy.

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$ mkdir NEWDIR

$ touch foo_file file_foo file_foo_file

$ ls
NEWDIR      file_foo    file_foo_file   foo_file

$ cp -v *foo NEWDIR/
file_foo -> NEWDIR/file_foo

$ cp -v foo* NEWDIR/
foo_file -> NEWDIR/foo_file

$ cp -v *foo* NEWDIR/
file_foo -> NEWDIR/file_foo
file_foo_file -> NEWDIR/file_foo_file
foo_file -> NEWDIR/foo_file

$ ls NEWDIR/
file_foo    file_foo_file   foo_file
```

Comment: what does -v do?

Comment: `-v` is the "verbose" flag, causing it to output exactly which files are being moved

Answer (score 11):

Try this statement: `cp *foo* /newdir`

Comment: Thanks, that's so simple, sorry for asking something so obvious!

Comment: NP - I don't want to hustle for rep but feel free to accept this answer :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you are really concerned about the number of files (e.g. running in the millions) you could use:

```
find . -type f -depth 1 -name "*foo*" -exec cp {} /otherdir \; -print
```

This doesn't use shell expansion, so you will not try to run a command with a million arguments. The `-print` gives you some indication of progress and can be left out. To simply list the files that are to be copied:

```
find . -type f -depth 1 -name "*foo*"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cp *foo* /path/to/separate_directory
```

If you want to validate the files that will be included first, the use:

```
ls *foo*
```

This will confirm the files to be matched, then you can re-use the same pattern with the cp command to execute the copy.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**globbing**](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html):

```
shopt -s failglob
echo cp *foo* /path/to/separate
```

This will output the copy command (or fail with `bash: no match: *foo*`).

Remove the `echo` when you've validated the output to actually *copy* the directory entries.

Comment: What benefit does the "echo" provide? It doesn't clarify which files are going to be included. If you want that, you'd want "ls *foo*" to confirm the files that will be matched, then "cp *foo* /target" to copy the same. Actually, I think I'll add that suggestion to my answer...

Comment: @DreadPirateShawn: Thanks for the comment. I've updated my answer (tested with Bash v4.2.37).